AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'_2024-07-11
When I directly run code debugging, it executes normally.
But when I used the pytest command to execute on terminal, this error occurred.

The current Python version is 3.12
Allure pytest version 2.13.5
Selenium version 4.22
Pytest version 8.2.2

How should I handle this problem?
Error message：
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "E:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\python\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_main())
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 206, in console_main
    code = main()
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 159, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 346, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 513, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls.copy(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 120, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 139, in _multicall
    raise exception.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 122, in _multicall
    teardown.throw(exception)  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 106, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = yield
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 103, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1152, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1501, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1388, in _preparse
    self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints("pytest11")
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 421, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "E:\python\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "E:\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 178, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\allure_pytest\plugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    import allure
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 178, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\allure\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from allure.pytest_plugin import MASTER_HELPER
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 178, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\allure\pytest_plugin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from allure.common import AllureImpl, StepContext
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 178, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\allure\common.py", line 19, in <module>
    from allure.structure import Attach, TestStep, TestCase, TestSuite, Failure, Environment, EnvParameter
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 178, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\allure\structure.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Attach(xmlfied('attachment',
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\allure\rules.py", line 116, in xmlfied
    class MyImpl(namedlist('XMLFied', [(item[0], None) for item in items])):
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\namedlist.py", line 398, in namedlist
    fields, defaults = _fields_and_defaults(typename, field_names, default, rename)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\namedlist.py", line 252, in _fields_and_defaults
    if isinstance(field_names, _collections.Mapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'


It's moved to collections.abc and finally removed from collections in python 3.10.
>>> from collections import Mapping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\~~~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\collections\__init__.py)

>>> from collections.abc import Mapping
>>> 

Remember to add your minimum reproducible example(MRE) code next time!
